# build error while deploying a html application in heroku

Tags: javascript, html, heroku

I have uploaded a html application in github but while trying to deploy it in heroku I am getting this error:

```
No default language could be detected for this app.
HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
!     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
```